# How to set up "sign in to network" page

Tags: wifi, setup, login

I' would like to set up a Sign in to wifi page (like many businesses have it in ther public wifi) for the wifi my Raspberry Pi hosts.

How do I set this up? Is there a specific port I have to use? Where do I set this up?

Comment: This is a general web programming question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a web server and deploy a piece of software called "captive portal".
An example of such software is [nodogsplash](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash), which is quite decently [documented](https://nodogsplashdocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Another one is [Kupiki Hotspot](https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script).